# AppCode is unable to build any Swift apps

Tags: swift, appcode

I am new to `Swift` and `AppCode` .

I am trying out existing projects for size and here is a set of interesting ones  https://github.com/soapyigu/Swift-30-Projects   In particular let's look at `Project 28 - SceneDetector`.

Here's the App in `Xcode`

[image]

And it works:

[image]

Here's the App in `AppCode`:  not even building and **no error details**.

[image]

We get just this:

[image]

I have tried to open multiple Apps with `AppCode` and even create one from scratch. Nothing works at all.   What am I misunderstanding?  I am using `Appcode 2019.3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now!  I have completely uninstalled two plugins  `R4Intellij` and `Haskell`.  Note that these were already *disabled* . Maybe uninstalling these got out of some bad mix of plugins code (disabled notwithstanding) for `AppCode`?

Debugger works!

[image]

Simulator launched from `AppCode`

[image]

**Update** This does not fix all cases. I am still running into the "Build failed" (without further information) at times.